# Swapping original string halves

Tags: javascript, html

Can I write a function that reads the content of an HTML textbox with id "message" and then writes into the HTML element with id "shuffled" with the value of original string with it's two halves swapped?

Examples:

```
"it" -> "ti"
"electric" -> "tricele"
"this laptop is lame" -> "op is lamethis lapt"
```

Comment: yup, you can. what problem are you having?

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yap it is possible, check this out:

```
var swap = function(str){
var half = Math.floor(str.length / 2);
return str.substr(half, str.length) + str.substr(0, half);
};

swap("electric"); // tricelec
```

Have fun :)